# Using foreach with ArrayList - automatic casting?

Tags: c#, casting, arraylist

```
ArrayList x=new ArrayList();
x.Add(10);
x.Add("SS");

foreach(string s in x)
{
}
```

Does it mean that when foreach is run it tries to cast element of array list to type in foreach expression?

Comment: I know what it does, just not sure whether there is internal casting from object to specified type.

Comment: Unfortunately `foreach` does implicitly cast the elements of x to the type specified for the loop variable even if the cast is normally explicit. One of the ugly things we inherited from pre generics times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, if an element is not convertible to the type, you'll get an `InvalidCastException`. In your case, you cannot cast boxed `int` to `string` causing an exception to be thrown.

Essentially, it's equivalent to:

```
foreach (object __o in list) {
    string s = (string)__o;
    // loop body
}
```

Answer (score 11):

According to c# [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx) of foreach statement, your code is equivalent to

```
ArrayList x=new ArrayList();
x.Add(10);
x.Add("SS");

IEnumerator enumerator = (x).GetEnumerator();
try {
   while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
      string element = (string)enumerator.Current; // here is casting occures
      // loop body;
   }
}
finally {
   IDisposable disposable = enumerator as System.IDisposable;
   if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course when you run that loop and cast it with , the compiler will try to cast it to the type specified, which in your case it will be String. and if it cannot do it it will raise an InvalidCastException.