# Acces method of a class, in iteration of foreach

Tags: c#, for-loop, arraylist, foreach, collections

I'm trying to acces to a method of a class, stored in an arraylist on a foreach, but it doesn't work.
For example:

Having the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int number;
    public MyClass()
    {
       this.number = 0;
    }
    public void addNumber(int add) 
    {
         this.number += add;
    }
}
```

If then in my main class i do this:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
ArrayList myarray = new ArrayList();
myarray.Add(myclass);
foreach ( MyClass mclss in myarray )
{
     mclss.addNumber(2);
}
```

It says "mclss does not contains any definition for addNumber..."
How can i do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How does this work then if it treats all items as `object` -> `foreach(MyClass mclss in myarray)`? The example looks like it is iterating each item as a `MyClass` type.

Comment: Despite the success of the compilation and the good functioning of the provided code, the class ArrayList is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist#remarks) and keeped for backward compatibility. If you can you should definitely use a `List<MyClass>` or anything more common conventional. I added the missing parenthesis at the foreach line.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any problem with the provided code. I think the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: I agree with @JohnWu, I ran this code in a .Net Fiddle and it added the number correctly. For anyone curious about the implicit cast of a `foreach` on an `ArrayList` - [using-foreach-with-arraylist-automatic-casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767528/using-foreach-with-arraylist-automatic-casting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using List<> instead of ArrayList worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You need to close the foreach bracket.
ie,

foreach(MyClass mclss in myarray)

Otherwise, this builds and runs fine.